# MySQL - Select userid from table if it appears in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

*Unfortunately I wasn't quite sure how to word this, so it may have been answered elsewhere but I couldn't find it. It seems like a simple question, anyway. I can think of long-winded ways of doing this, but considering that I'm fairly new to SQL I wasn't wondering what the most efficient way would be.*

Below is an example of the data I have: two joined tables.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
userid    attributeid    attributename    attributetype
-------------------------------------------------------
1         1              Python           Skill
1         5              C++              Skill
1         2              London           Location
2         1              Python           Skill
2         3              Warsaw           Location
3         4              MySQL            Skill
3         2              London           Location
```

**ISSUE:** Basically, I want to end up with the IDs of users which have the skill ('Python' OR 'MySQL') AND the location 'London'.

So in this example, I would end up with User IDs 1 and 3.

Any thoughts? Please direct me elsewhere if this has been tackled before.

Comment: `SELECT userid FROM [[Table]] WHERE attributename IN ('Python', 'MySQL') AND attributetype='Skill' AND userid IN (SELECT userid from [[TABLE]] WHERE attributename = 'London' AND attributetype='Location')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a standard setup with a *users* and an *attributes* table. Try this query:

```
SELECT userid
FROM users
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM attributes
     WHERE users.userid = attributes.userid
       AND attributetype = 'Skill'
       AND attributename IN ('Python',
                             'MySQL'))
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM attributes
     WHERE users.userid = attributes.userid
       AND attributetype = 'Location'
       AND attributename = 'London')
```

Comment: Fantastic... simple, and it worked! I actually have three tables: User, Attributes and a userAttributes junction table to link the two. The table above is a sample of the Attributes and userAttributes tables joined together pivoted on AttributeId (sorry, I should've been clearer), but tweaking this a bit I was able to get a solution - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
select userid from tag where attributetype='Skill' AND 
attributename IN ('Python','MySQL') AND userid IN
(select distinct(userid) from tag where 
  (attributetype='Location' AND attributename='London'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic query that should get you the results you requested:

```
SELECT `userid`
FROM `table_name_goes_here`
WHERE (`attributename` IN ('Python', 'MySQL') AND `attributetype` = 'Skill')
AND (`attributename` IN ('London') AND `attributetype` = 'Location')
GROUP BY `userid`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join,One for `attributetype` is Skill and other for `attributetype` is Location and then adjust  your conditions for `attributename`

```
select t.*
from t
join t t1 on(t.userid= t1.userid)
where t.attributetype ='Skill'
and t1.attributetype ='Location'
  and t.attributename  in('Python','MySQL')
 and t1.attributename  = 'London'
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3a82/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userId
FROM table
WHERE attributename = 'London'
    AND attributename in ('MySQL', 'Python')
```